# Why $_SESSION['token'] value changes on page load?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I created the script. Source -

Controller -

```
 public function action_index() {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['token'] = rand();
if (isset($_GET['do']) and $_GET['do'] == 'comment') {//Ja viss kārtībā, turpinam
            var_dump($_POST['token']);
            var_dump($_SESSION['token']);
            if ($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {
echo 'ok';
}
else{ echo 'error'; }
```

View -

```
<form action="?do=comment" class="form-komentaram" method="post" style="margin: 7.5px;">
    <input type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Tavs vārds..." /><br />
    <input type="text" name="homepage" placeholder="Tava mājaslapa..." /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="artcl_id" value="<?php echo $article['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
    <textarea name="text" required="required"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK!" required="required" />
</form>
```

With var_dump I see, that $_SESSION['token'] changes on page load.
For example, I submit token in input field and reload page to check tokens, but $_SESSION['token'] before page reload was 23456, and $_POST['token'] is 23456, but after page reload $_SESSION['token'] is 12345. Why?

Comment: Because of `$_SESSION['token'] = rand();` probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you posted, $_SESSION['token'] would be replaced with a new value every time action_index() is called. Should do something like:

```
if (!array_key_exists('token', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = rand();
}
```

Then any subsequent calls to action_index() won't keep overriding your session token value.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're assigning it a random value each time the page is loaded.

```
        $_SESSION['token'] = rand();
```

Then you're echoing it as a hidden input.
    " />

So next time you submit the form it will have the echoed value.

If you're wanting to assign it once for the session, then do:

```
if (!$_SESSION['token']) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = rand();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['token'] = rand();
```

You explicitly change the value of `$_SESION['token']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['token'] = rand();
```

The very first thing you do when using the session here is set `$_SESSION['token']` to a random value.  So every time the code is used the value will be different.  (Or, at least, is *very* likely to be different.)

You probably want to check for a value before assigning it a random value, or assign the random value when the session begins elsewhere in the code and not on each page load.